# Começar frases com infinitivo

Tags: infinitivo-pessoal

Hoje em dia, ouve-se muitas vezes usar o infinitivo dos verbos para começar frases.
Uma jornalista em direto de um local diz repetidamente:

- "Dizer que o incêndio está controlado..." ou
- "Dizer também que não há registo de danos."

Está correcto?

Comment: “Navegar é preciso; viver não é preciso” Uma música. Claro que se pode começar uma frase com o infinitivo. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlPIf5vCvgc Se usa para fazer frases tipo declarações.

Answer (score 1):

Não há problema nenhum em se iniciar frases com um verbo no inifitivo, porque o verbo no infinitivo pode ser tratado como um substantivo:

- Ser ou não ser, eis a questão (William Shakespeare, em Hamlet)
- Navegar é preciso; viver não é preciso (Fernando Pessoa)
- Errar é humano, permanecer no erro é burrice (ditado popular)
- [Esta página](https://www.pensador.com/frases_perfeitas_para_refletir_sobre_o_que_e_amar/) traz vários exemplos com o verbo *amar*.

Answer (score -2):

eu acho horrível e corto os pulsos sempre que ouço alguém falar dessa forma. O CHatgpt diz que é ok "Sim, em português europeu é comum e gramaticalmente correto começar frases com o verbo no infinitivo, especialmente em contextos informais ou coloquiais. Expressões como "começar por falar sobre..." ou "dizer também que..." são utilizadas frequentemente para introduzir um tópico ou adicionar informações a uma discussão. Esta estrutura é bastante flexível e amplamente aceita na língua portuguesa." No entanto, todos sabemos que o chatgpt se engana muito!

Comment: Na verdade pode ser muito formal. Chatgpt não sabe nada.

Comment: @Lambie, o problema é que as pessoas confundem uma I.A. que gera texto com uma inteligência que se expressa. O ChatGPT, literalmente, não sabe nada.